# Background-image of an element with a border should overlay the border

Tags: css, background, border, background-image, z-index

I currently have an h4 with a background and a border.

[image]

The marked border on the left and the border on top and bottom have to be gone on that area where the blue background image lays.

In final, it should look like this:

[image]

My Idea was that I lay the background over the border via `z-index:`, which does not work, since the border belongs to the same element as the background.

My current code looks like this:

```
.workstations .textbox h4 { 
    display: inline-block; 
    color: #3391cc; 
    font-size: 1em; font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 100%;
    background: url(images/workstations_bg.png) no-repeat; 
    border: 1px solid #dedede; 
    padding: 14px 0 9px 25px;
    } 

.workstations .textbox h4 span {
    display: inline-block; 
    color: #e86228;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    }
```

Anyway to do it? I tried doing something like

`.workstations .textbox h4 background-image {
z-index: 100;}
.workstations .textbox h4 border { z-index: 50;}`

Which does not work...

Any help?

Comment: The whole point of a background is to appear *behind* the border. That's why it's a *back*ground. What exactly is this background image? If it's just a blue vertical strip then you can just set that as the left border instead of using an image.

Comment: There should still be away... you know, just because I have a border, it does not mean it backgrounds an element.

Comment: Could be a good idea, but it does not work out 100%. There are a few transition errors from the adjoining borders.

Comment: Like BoltClock says if it's a single color background, use a left border at the same width as your background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to split the blue part of your background off and then if you put a `span` inside your `h4` you can use something like:

```
h4 {background:url(http://originalimage) left center no-repeat; border:1px solid red;}
h4 span {display:block; margin:-1px 0 -1px -1px; padding:5px 10px 5px 55px; /*use the span for your padding and pad left enough for the blue*/ background:url(http://blueimage) left center no-repeat;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XUNJe/